# How to graph bracketed price ranges in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to graph the following data:

```
    # Min   # Max   $/#     Flat
    1       20      50      100
    21      50      45      200
    51      100     40      300
    101     180     35      400
    181     254     30      500
    255     400     25      1000
```

How could I make a graph with # on the X-axis, and `(# * $/#) + Flat` on the Y?

I've found tutorials for bar graphs, but nothing to find a curve for this.

I would like it to look like this:

Hand-drawn version of what I want it to look like
[image]

And be smart enough that if I change the min and max ranges, it will update.

(EDIT: Yeah, I know I messed up some of the brackets in my drawing. This is why I graph via computer - Haha.)

Comment: Added :) - I hope its good enough.

Comment: Is `# * $/#) + Flat` a formula? What's `#`? The Min or Max?  Have you created a column to hold that formula's output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel need to have the exact coordinates to plot a chart, it can't make charts based on rules. So you need to transform your data first.

1. enter x coordinates

   - with the setup according to the picture; enter `F2:F401` in the address bar (top left corner where you see the address of the active cell) and press enter, this will select 400 cells for you
   - type `=ROW()-1` and press CTRL+ENTER
2. enter y coordinates

   - in g2 enter formula:
     `=F2*VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$D$7,3,TRUE)+VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$D$7,4,TRUE)`
     and press ENTER
   - select F3 and press CTRL+Down (this will go to bottom of data in column D)
   - select G401 and press CTRL+SHIFT+UP
   - press CTRL+D to fill down the formula in column G
3. insert the chart

   - select any cell in your new range
   - go to insert - chart - scatter, select "scatter with straight lines"

[image]

notes:

- I used the formula in the question, that results a chart different from the picture
- posted picture has gaps, to have it in Excel, you would need x coordinates without y value

Comment: I confirmed the graph shape you obtained with a nasty IF piece-wise function: `=IF(G2<21,G2*50+100,IF(G2<51,G2*45+200,IF(G2<101,G2*40+300,IF(G2<181,G2*35+400,IF(G2<255,G2*30+500,G2*25+1000)))))`

Comment: Thank you! It seems my mental math for the the picture was backwards.